Chaining requests to PokeAPI
My app have to connect to PokeApi to obtain 12 random pokemons,now it's doing this by randomly selecting 12 pokemon IDs and calling the API 12 times in the form:
fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${id}`)

I wonder if there's some way to chain those IDs in the url and recieve 12 objects in one JSON.
My full fetching code:
export async function fetchPokemons() {
  let pokemonIDs = [];

  let pokemons = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    pokemonIDs.push(getRandomPokemonID());
  }
  const promises = pokemonIDs.map(async (id) => {
    const promise = await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${id}`);
    return promise.json();
  });
  pokemons = await Promise.all(promises);
  console.log(pokemons);
  pokemons = pokemons.map((pokemon) => ({
    id: pokemon.id,
    pokeName: pokemon.name,
    image: pokemon.sprites.other["official-artwork"].front_default,
    reactID: uuidv4(),
  }));

  return pokemons;
}


Probably not. But if, this should be described in the docs
